# What is the word for this type of pawn or figurine?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image: map figurines]

Is there a specific name for this type of figurine? Specifically, I mean a sculpture with a column for a base and some kind of animal head emerging from it?

You commonly see this type of figure on fictional battlefield maps denoting where ally and enemy troops are.

Edit: Further researching shows that a similar object, but with a human head is called a 'term'[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(architecture)). Though these seem to be much larger.

Comment: The closest that immediately springs to mind is ***caryatid***, though that's usually reserved for the architectural device.

Comment: @DanBron: *Caryatid* has a specific meaning that does not include this.

Comment: Yale University apparently calls this kind of thing an ["animal head figurine"](https://artgallery.yale.edu/collections/objects/52140).

Comment: @Robusto Did the rest of the comment carrying that word to your mind not convey that caveat? Starting with "closest that springs to mind" and ending with "usually reserved for"?

Comment: @DanBron: Nope. It didn't. A brick may be the closest thing that springs to mind when discussing a bale of hay, but that doesn't mean it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Dan The closest that springs to my mind is a "bust". A caryatid is way too specific. It has to be specifically a female bust and it has to hold stuff on its head, and it has to be not necessarily a bust at all.

Comment: Apparently a similar concept, but with a human head is called a 'Term'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(architecture)

Comment: @Robusto Given the architectural trail led Samuel even closer to his goal, it seems it was worth mentioning.

Comment: I’ve gone with gaming terminology in my answer, but IIRC, on [Time Comanders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Commanders), the individual pieces were just called what they represented: enemy heavy horse, archers etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sculptures consisting of the head and shoulders are called *[busts](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bust_1)*, and chess pieces consisting of busts on a base are called *[bust chess pieces](https://www.straightupchess.com/product-p/colored-medieval-bust.htm)*, so you can generically call the pieces illustrated *bust game pieces*.

Comment: This seems like the closest answer. "animal bust" seems to yield at least similar results to the examples.

Answer (score 1):

They resemble game or chess pieces, hence in describing them you may want to use that terminology.

Comment: Indeed! But "pawn" seems a bit too generic a term.

Answer (score 0):

[**Meeple**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meeple) might be a suitable word. According to the Oxford Dictionaries definition:

> A small figure used as a playing piece in certain board games, having a stylized human form.

However I’ve seen it generalised to include other game pieces. It’s pretty specific to game tokens, and also a new word.